# Difference between <html:html></html:html> and <html></html>

Tags: java, html, jsp

Good day all,

I saw `<html:html></html:html>` from a jsp page in a java project.

Would like to ask what is the difference between these html tags.

Kindly advise.

The example code is as follow:

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %>
<html:html> 
<head>
</head>

<body>
<!-- some html code here -->
</body>
</html:html>
```

Comment: Post a basic example including the file headers and the definitions in the file. Surely the `<html:html>` is part of a tag preffix whose name is `html` and causing this confusion.

Comment: As said in my previous comment, there's a taglib with `html` preffix. There's no such `<html:html>` tag nor in JSP nor in Facelets, this is a Struts 1 tag, so your question is about the usage of html struts taglib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<html:html>` uses the struts-html tag library, where `<html></html>` is just plain old html.

You can read all about the struts-html taglib [here](http://struts.apache.org/release/1.3.x/struts-taglib/dev_html.html).

Comment: Way to turn my comment in answer

Answer (score 1):

both are same.html:html is struts 1 tag which is equal to basic HTML's html tag.